# Heroku seems not to support gspread

Tags: python, heroku, chatbot, gspread

I was trying creating my line chatbot using python and I chose heroku as my chatbot sever.
Everything goes well but as long as I add the following code, my chatbot can't work.

> import gspread

I was wondering why it happened.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are missing the package `gspread` on your server.

Run the following command on the server and it should solve your issue:

```
python3 -m pip install gspread
```

It will install the gspread package.